# dynamically created a tag onclick function not triger in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have developed a web app using jquery mobile. I wanted to call a function by clicking on the anchor tag which I've created dynamically. but it's not triggering and says the function is not defined. any help will highly be appreciated.

here is my code

```
function itemSearch(para) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:4000/products/filter/"+para,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {

            let output='';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                let img="http://localhost:4000/"+data[i].ImgPath.replace("Product\\","");
                output +=`
                    <li>
                        <a onclick="itemClicked('${data[i]._id}')" href="#" >
                            <img src="${img}">
                            <h3>${data[i].Category}</h3>
                            <p>Price : ${data[i].Price}</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    `
                $('#items').html(output).listview('refresh');
                $('#search').val("");
            }
        }
    });
}

function itemClicked(id) {
 alert(id);
}
```

Comment: Is `itemClicked` defined in the global scope?

Comment: @Taplar no its inside my onload function but when i call the function outside the anchor tag its calling without issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `itemClicked` function is declared inside the scope of another function, the `<a>` tag cannot access it.

This demonstrates the problem, the solution is to move `itemClicked` to the global scope.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  function itemClicked () {
    alert('itemClicked');
  }
}();

function globalIemClicked () {
    alert('globalIemClicked');
}
```

```html
<a onclick="itemClicked()" href="#">Run itemClicked</a><br/>
<a onclick="globalIemClicked()" href="#">Run globalitemClicked</a>
```